# How to prove the following related with regular languages

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

How can we prove the following. If $$\sum$$ is any alphabet and L is any language $$L \subset \sum*$$ Then L*L* = L* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\epsilon \in L^\star$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty word, it's clear that $L^\star L^\star \supset L^\star$.

Now, let $\omega \in L^\star L^\star$. Then $\omega = \omega_{1,1}\ldots\omega_{1,n}\omega_{2,1}\ldots\omega_{2,m}$ with all $\omega_{i,j} \in L$, by the definition of $\star$ and concatenation. But every word of the form $\omega'_1\ldots\omega'_k$, where all $\omega'_i \in L$, lies in $L^\star$... I'm leaving the rest to you.

Comment: FGITW if I've ever seen one. Nice answer.

Comment: ...That means $$L^* \subset L^*L^*$$ which means we proved in both directions that $$L^*L^* \subset L^*$$ and $$ L^* \subset L^*L^*$$ which implies $$L^*L^* = L^*$$. Is that right?

Comment: The second paragraph means $L^\star L^\star \subset L^\star$, not the other way around, but apart from that, yes.